# xcopy is not working in Visual studio 2013 64 bit, exited with code 1

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, xcopy

I have a below code in postbuild event

*xcopy "$(TargetDir)*.*" "$(ProjectDir)..\Libraries" /I /D /R /Y*

The error i am getting is below:

```
Error   1   The command "xcopy 
"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Versioning\Versioning\bin\Debug\*.*" 
"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Versioning\Versioning\..\Libraries"
 /I /D /R /Y" exited with code 1.
```

I already Tried:

1. Giving full permission for both source and destination folder
2. able to browse source and destination path displayed above.
3. same command is working fine from command prompt and able to copy files.
4. same command even working fine in **VS2010 x86 bit**
5. problem only exist in **VS2013 x64 bit**.
6. restarting system, vs all approaches failed to fix this issue

Comment: 1. It`s fresh build laptop there is nothing in this other than vs2013, so Anti-malware is not possible and it is Library project and it is generating dll and I am trying to copy that dll to common library folder[No exe file present at all].

2. And I am performing the build, No website and nothing is runnig.
 
3. I set the below option and tried to figure out the problem

"Tools => Options => Projects and Solutions => Build and Run => MSBuild project build output verbosity" to "Diagnostic"

Output is in next comment

Comment: 1>  Task Parameter:WorkingDirectory=bin\Debug\ (TaskId:41)
1>  Task Parameter:Command=xcopy "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Versioning\Versioning\bin\Debug\*.*" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Versioning\Versioning\..\Libraries" /I /D /R /Y: (TaskId:41)
1>  xcopy "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Versioning\Versioning\bin\Debug\*.*" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Versioning\Versioning\..\Libraries" /I /D /R /Y: (TaskId:41)
1>  'C:\Users\BhanurajKM\AppData\Local\Temp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, (TaskId:41)

Comment: continued output...

1>  operable program or batch file. (TaskId:41)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4548,5): error MSB3073: The command "xcopy "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Versioning\Versioning\bin\Debug\*.*" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Versioning\Versioning\..\Libraries" /I /D /R /Y <NUL:" exited with code 1.
1>Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED. (TaskId:41)